# How to send express-session to client not in same url?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, express-session

Can I please get some help, I have been searching all over the internet for this and I cannot seem to find the answer that I am looking for.

So I would love to implement expression-session and mongoDB as the store, so session creation I managed to get that done and also saving the session within the store i.e MongoDB managed to get that done.

The problem now comes to when I have to send the session cookie to the client, so I have my server(NodeJS) running on port 5000 and I have the client(ReactJS) running on port 3000, so now how can I send that cookie to the client and flag it as httpOnly cookie?

**This is how I tried to setup express-session**

```
mongoose
  .connect(MongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected..."))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
const mongoDBstore = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: MongoURI,
  collection: "mySessions"
});
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  session({
    name: COOKIE_NAME, 
    secret: 'SESS_SECRET',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: mongoDBstore,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3,
      sameSite: false,
      secure: false
    }
  })
);
```

**This is where I wanted to send the cookie once user logs in**

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Please enter all fields" });
  }
  User.findOne({ email }).then((user) => {
    if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "User does not   exist" });
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then((isMatch) => {
      if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid    credentials" });
      const sessUser = { id: user.id, name: user.name, email:   user.email };
      req.session.user = sessUser; 
      res.json({ msg: " Logged In Successfully", sessUser });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Cookies are not port specific so a cookie set on a request on port 3000 will work just fine for requests from the same client to the same host on port 5000.  If you aren't seeing the cookie sent, then you need to look at how the client is making the request  and see if it is properly configured to include cookies with its requests.

Comment: If you want further help with setting the cookie, then show us the actual code where you want to send the cookie back so we can advise specifically on how to modify that actual code.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry for late response I was having issues with network but I just added the code where I tried to set up express-session and then also where I tried to send the cookie from the server to the client

Comment: So, your session middleware will send a session cookie to the calling client.  Please describe the exact sequence of requests and describe where you don't see the cookie.

Comment: Okay so when user logs in I successfully make a session and get the session saved in MongoDB using the **connect mongo lib** but then I fail to send the session cookie to the client. So basically the sequence is on user log in I want to send the httpOnly to React client

Comment: What exact client request does the login?  Please show that client code.  What exact client request comes later and does not have the session cookie.  Please show that client code.  Then, show the server code where you're not seeing the session.  We have to be able to follow the entire flow here.

Comment: On the client I am just sending an axios post request with the email and password, if you can within the code provided I have the **router.post** that is responsible for validating user login and I also attempted to send through the user session cookie but failed. So on the client the is nothing much than axios post request unless the was something that I needed to do?